# Where can I find a full featured demo application of a scala web application with a db backend?

Tags: scala, lift, demo

I've been really interested in scala for awhile.  Now that Intellij 13 has better Scala support it seems like its becoming more and more practical to work with.  For example they have SBT support.

Now I have a bit of a finicky learning style.  If I could find an operating example of a Scala application with Lift using

SBT for build
A relational database and ORM
Lift

I'd be able to pick this up a lot faster.  A lot of the demos I've found are way way too small to be usefull.

Anybody have a suggestion for where to find a fully features open source app in Scala?

Answer (score 1):

They have some Lift "quickstart projects" [here](http://liftweb.net/download). Some more examples [here](http://demo.liftweb.net/). And of course, Lift's [Github](https://github.com/lift), where you can find project templates (more specifically, look at [this link](https://github.com/lift/lift_26_sbt)).

There is also [Typesafe](https://typesafe.com/), but they offer Play instead of Lift.

Answer (score 1):

Lift has 2 db layers. They are mapper and record. Record is little more modern in my opinion.

The next thing: record can have different backends for work with database. I use squeryl ( good introduction is here - http://squeryl.org/introduction.html )

And the last thing, you can use different databases, of course: mysql, postgresql, mongodb, etc, you see...

What about me - I use lift squeryl record with postgresql.

What about examples:

Not so bad *full* _simple_ example (book shop but without user as i remember) is here, see https://github.com/migo/test-squerylrecord .

Comment: Also three more links.   
   
User authorization (with a little bit of README to start) is here: https://github.com/karma4u101/Basic-SquerylRecord-User-Setup   .
   
One more small example with squery record (with README too): https://github.com/oolekk/sqrlrcrd.com   .
   
Blog record about how to build your own CRUDify instead of lift's MegaProgoUser: http://tech.damianhelme.com/diy-lift-crud-an-alternative-to-crudify/ .